# How can I get this array of numbers sorted?

Tags: bash

I have an array called colNums that looks like this:

```
1         
5         
4       
2    
2     
7
```

When I print the array with echo "$colNums" it prints like that. I want this list sorted.

I'm trying

```
    sortedColNums=($(for i in "${colNums[@]}"; do echo $i; done | sort -n))
```

but for some reason sortedNumCols only contains the first number, 1. Can anyone help?

EDIT: It turned out I had a string rather than an array. I got it into a sorted string with the second answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625976/sorting-space-delimited-numbers-with-linux-bash

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you provide some actual runnable code that exhibits the issue you're having?

Comment: Actually, wait, `echo "$colNums"` can't possibly print like that if colNums is an array. You have a string with newlines in it.

Comment: Whoops, thanks. Do you know how I can break it into an array?

Comment: Add output of `declare -p colNums` to your question.

Comment: `colNums=($colNums)`

Comment: You can also send it into `sort` directly as it is.

Comment: Hmm, colNums=($colNums) doesn't seem to work. I'll need to get it into a sorted array of numbers somehow. Cyrus, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Arrays are accessed using square bracket notation, which you already used in your "`in`" clause, not as `"$colNums"`, which I think you're trying to use. Cyrus is asking you to copy and paste.

Comment: `colNums=$(sort <<< "$colNums")`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
sortedColNums=( $( printf "%s\n" "${colNums[@]}" | sort -n ) )
```